# GK Bike Store Ecommerce template problem

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

Im gonna create an online shop using this template: https://www.gavick.com/joomla-templates/responsive-ecommerce-virtuemart-joomla-template,92
But it says that the template only supports VirtueMart 2.6 and I have to use Joomla 2.5...
My question is... can't I install VM 2.6 in Joomla 3.X (?)

Comment: Some of the [newer templates](https://www.gavick.com/joomla-templates/tag,VirtueMart) from Gavick supports VirtueMart 3, namely Storefront, Instyle, Shop&Buy and Storebox.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

For starters, the XML file uses the `<install>` tags which were used in Joomla 1.5 but still compatible in 2.5, so trying to install it will result in:

> Warning
>
> > JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file.

In addition to that, it's probably using older coding standards, which will result in PHP errors

I would simply suggest finding another template that's compatible with VirtueMart 3.x (Joomla 3.x)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this quite long tread](https://www.gavick.com/forums/bike-store/updating-bike-store-to-joomla-3-x-and-vm-3-x-42732) from the GK Forums, the template has been updated with a Joomla 3/VM3-compatible version (just scroll down almost to the bottom):

> Yes. Bike store form J3.x and VM3.x was released 2 days ago

That way you can install the J3-compatible template and run your site using the latest Joomla and VM versions (unless you've already found another solution to your problem :)